# Get maximum value based on unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, pivot-table, array-formulas

I have two columns in Excel as follows:

```
col1  col2

1     10
1     22
1     11
1     23
1     14
2     16
2     12
2     10
2     9
```

How do I write a command to returns the  maximum value from `col2` corresponding to each unique value in `col1`?

So here I need to write a command to get `23` and `16`.

The data I have shown here are dummies; I have 600 unique values in `col1` in my actual data set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pivot tables: the single most underutilized and powerful feature of excel.

- File menu:
- Insert
- Pivot Table
- Select range
- Fill in as indicated in image below

[image]

Step by Step:

- Place cursor in cell to right of all data on sheet.
- Select insert from menu
- select pivot table icon
- select pivot table from pop-up of icon
- use the button to select the range of cells included (all 600+ rows in 2 columns) (or just enter $A:$B)
- select ok
- A pivot table field list appears on the right:
- Drag and drop row 1 into row labels.
- drag and drop row 2 into values area.
- left click on "... of Row 2"
- select value field settings
- select "Max" instead of count or sum
- select ok and you should have desired results.

The pivot table will find the max value in row 2 for each unique value in row 1 which is what I believe you are after.

Comment: how could you tell me? I still dont get it, i tried pivot table

Comment: @kira updated with instructions (note the MAX) for values used and Row labels as "Row 1"

Comment: I mean, there are only 2 distinct values here, so pivot may help,  but with the actual data i have, there are 600 unique values in column1 , then what

Comment: hey xqbert, images are blocked over my office net, could you please tell me what all did you put where?

Comment: @kira updated with complete step by step instructions (for office 2010)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, sorry for the trouble. Also, could you link me to any matarial that shows these ingenious methods of using pivot tables?

Comment: @Kira http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/training/pivottable-i-what-s-so-great-about-pivottable-reports-RZ001013617.aspx http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-create-pivot-table-excel , and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ffdXfriLPQ are but a few...

Answer (score 4):

Even if a solution has been found. I think it is too complicated and oversized to use the pivot for this and it might not be possible in all scenarios. Here is one that can be found searching the internet for "max if excel" (e.g. see [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2010functions/qt/2010-04-26-excel-2010-max-function.htm); adapted)

{=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))}

Attention! This is an array formula, you have to enter it without the curly brackets and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to submit the formula.

Comment: @xQbert No. It works like the normal max function just with the if part.

Answer (score 2):

Since the left hand values seem to be in order, Subtotal should work.

Comment: Great option too. Select data from file menu... select range.  then select subtotal change use function to max (but note the data has to be ordered for it to work as indicated)