# Count of Cell Value by value in column a

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

In my table I have

```
Column A = Date, 
Column B= Name, 
Column C = Item number.
```

Basically instead of me going and manually counting how many times a item (column B) was used in a day (column A), is there a way for excel to do that?

So I want to count how many times a item name appears in a day in Excel.

Comment: Have you looked into the [COUNTIF-function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

```
Date    Name    Item
12-Nov  Jim Hammer
12-Nov  Sue Hammer
12-Nov  Sue Saw
12-Nov  Bob Pliers
13-Nov  Jim Saw
13-Nov  Bob Pliers
```

I think you'd like to count how many times each item got used on each day. Excel has a pivot table. (Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406475/509840 for a step-by-step use of a pivot table.)

I made a pivot chart like this.
[image: Basic pivot chart]

As you can see, it has given the total for each item as well as a grand total.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Filter option to filter out a particualar day, and select the Item cells ,  We can see the count below the excel sheet itself

Answer (score 0):

You can build a pivot [as explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955845/1008588) by user rajah9 or you can use the formula **COUNTIFS** (which is an evolute version of **COUNTIF** function).

Just set the function to count the item (column B) and the day (column A) you want.

You can refer to [this official guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx).