# Excel file - Keep the most recent for each ID

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with this kind of data:

```
ID1 XXX YYY 22/11/1987
ID1 ZZZ AAA 23/11/1987 
ID2 ZZZ AAA 23/11/1987
```

In that case, I would like to keep, for each ID (other fields might be differents), the most recent one, which would lead me with:

```
ID1 ZZZ AAA 23/11/1987 
ID2 ZZZ AAA 23/11/1987
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use PivotTables to achieve this quick. Have a look [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406328/get-maximum-value-based-on-unique-values)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in four columns (A:D) you might apply an array formula (CSE entry) such as:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,D:D))=D1
```

(although it would be preferable to restrict the number of rows to something manageable) in Row 1 and copied down to suit, to identify (by `FALSE`) rows to be deleted with Filter.