# Max Min Tide Heights

Tags: excel, max, min, tidal-scheduler

I am trying to build up a tidal table. I already have the tidal height per day and for every 5 min.

My problem is now to determine the high and low tide heights values per day from those values.

So far I have done it "by hand" with a max formula 
=IF(E12=MAX($E$2:$E$289),MAX($E$2:$E$289), "")
[image]

not practical at all... can anyone help me?

Comment: You can create a PivotTable based on your data, to get the max and min values. Have a look on [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406328/get-maximum-value-based-on-unique-values) one.

Comment: IF you are not interested in the pivot table approach, are you open to using helper cells?

Answer (score 2):

To do it in one formula:

MAX:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$28,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$2:$E$28=AGGREGATE(14,6,$E$2:$E$28/(INT($D$2:$D$28)=INT($H2)),1))*(INT($D$2:$D$28)=INT($H2)),),0))
```

MIN:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$28,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E$2:$E$28=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$2:$E$28/(INT($D$2:$D$28)=INT($H2)),1))*(INT($D$2:$D$28)=INT($H2)),),0))
```

[image]

Then format the cells in which the formulas reside as time.  Otherwise it will show the full date.

Comment: Shooting fish in a barrel for you. Now do it without using `index/match` =P

Comment: @findwindow then I would need to use OFFSET or INDIRECT and I hate those formulas.

Comment: do I even need to look at scott's answers or can I just upvote as soon as he puts something up? 8) WAIT A SECOND.  I believe in my original comment I said dynamically pick the range for the source data.  if I read this right, Scott cheated and hard coded it at 28 rows! 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd you can upvote but because I have hit the max, hence why I did not answer earlier, I will get no points added.  But we are all here to help and learn.  That is why I ended up posting.

Comment: lol @ForwardEd I just upvote instantly then read later. But yea! Scott did cheat.

Comment: @ScottCraner lol hit max for the day. I cry for you =P Edit: also lol, didn't know you could do it without `index/match` XD

Answer (score 1):

first generate a list of unique dates

place this in column H and copy down as needed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1564,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$1:$H1,$A$2:$A$1564),0,0),0)),"")
```

and that should generate a list of unique dates.  Then beside each date we will search for a max and a min.  so in column I use the following for MIN

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$2:$E$1564/($A$2:$A$1564=I2),1)
```

and then in column J for MAX use:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$E$2:$E$1564/($A$2:$A$1564=I2),1)
```

Replace 1564 with your last row.  Copy the formulas from row 2 down to the last unique date you have.

Comment: Not bad. Wonder if @scottcraner can do it with just one formula =P

Comment: Uh... I am sorry but he's _my_ mentor.

Comment: @findwindow the hard part is beating Scott to the answer!

Comment: you probably could do it with one formula, but I think you would want to know what dates the max and the min were referring to.   So I think you are looking at at least three cells of information.  Now you could potentially put it into an array formula but why?  I hate working with CSE formulas but do so when I must.

Comment: Yea, it would likely have to be array. Edit: it's just fun to watch Scott nest a million functions into one formula.

Comment: I think the more challenging part would be to make the range that is being checked dynamic without using an offset.  OUR MENTOR claims to use INDEX instead of OFFSET in most situation due to the recalc or offset if it is being called multiple times.

Comment: @findwindow I tend to pile my formulas into one cell as well, but I usually start by laying the steps out in adjacent columns then back substituting to get one ugly and unruly formula usually.  It works but what a pain to figure out later.

Comment: That's what separates Scott from the mortals. He just nests it at 100mph.

Comment: @findwindow and ForwardEd See my answer.  You guys give me too much credit.  There are many others out here that can do more than I.

Comment: @ScottCraner With formulas, nah, you're the bestest.